# What is the Benefit If a Stochastic Process is a Submartingale?

Tags: probability-theory, soft-question, martingales

> Suppose if I have a stochastic process which is a submartingale. What is the "practical" benefit from this property?

I have a roughly idea that this submartingale property suggests a favorable game scenario which is better than the fair game scenario (e.g., if a stochastic process is a martingale, then it can be used to model a fair game). But I'm pretty interested to know if there are any other practical benefits if a stochastic process is a submartingale process?

Comment: Submartingales have a lot of nice properties that you can exploit. The work done by Doob alone (optional stopping, martingale convergence theorem, maximal inequality etc. ) should be convincing enough for that. You could take a look at Williams's Probability with Martingales to know more about some of these properties.

Comment: @Calculon, Thank you . Could you point out some references or textbook so that I can take a look?

Answer (score 1):

A submartingale can be [decomposed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob_decomposition_theorem#Corollary) into a martingale and a previsible process